# Append data to the beginning of each entry in a 2d list

Tags: python, list

I've got two lists.  One is a normal list the other is a 2d list.  I need to take 4 entries from list 1 and add them (preferably in a certain order like pushing them) to the front of each entry on the second 2d list.

I need the first four pieces of list one below

```
['15', '15:09 WED JAN 10 2018', 'Endcrinology', '0', '20', '0:00', '', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']
```

added to each "values" entry in list two...

```
(0, ['Check In', '', '1607-584-4547', 'Avail', '10:48', '3', '1', '1'])
(1, ['Check In', '', '1607-584-4514', 'Avail', '10:49', '2', '1', '12'])
(2, ['Check Out', '', '1607-584-4580', 'Avail', '10:46', '2', '0', '3'])
(3, ['Check Out', '', '1607-115-4068', 'AUX', '10:49', '0', '0', '8'])
```

I'm already iterating through list 2 in order to shave off a few tabs that cause 1-4 element groups after the end of the "real data" like this:

```
    for element, value in enumerate(agentdata1):
        if len(value) != 8:
            agentdata1.pop(element)
```

My thought was that still inside the for loop but outside the if statement I could "push" these values onto the list.  I've messed around with list.insert and list.append but haven't had any joy yet.  Thanks in advance.

The desired output is below:

```
(0, ['15', '15:09 WED JAN 10 2018', 'Endcrinology', '0','Check In', '', '1607-584-4547', 'Avail', '10:48', '3', '1', '1'])
(1, ['15', '15:09 WED JAN 10 2018', 'Endcrinology', '0','Check In', '', '1607-584-4514', 'Avail', '10:49', '2', '1', '12'])
(2, ['15', '15:09 WED JAN 10 2018', 'Endcrinology', '0','Check Out', '', '1607-584-4580', 'Avail', '10:46', '2', '0', '3'])
(3, ['15', '15:09 WED JAN 10 2018', 'Endcrinology', '0','Check Out', '', '1607-115-4068', 'AUX', '10:49', '0', '0', '8'])
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: your code currently removes elements from a list while iterating on it. Don't do that.

Comment: Jean-Francois, Why is that?  The idea is that I want to verify that each element in the list is a full 8 pieces of data.  Then any element that is not (should only be the last one) gets popped.  That bit of code is in a much larger loop that builds many of these lists and appends them to a single large list at the end.  The whole thing is ugly, it's CLI scraping so it won't be able to be pretty but I'm interested in "better ways" to accomplish it.  right now that code is working though.

Comment: Ajax1234:  added desired output above

Comment: @ddickenson because it is a common source of bugs unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Any suggestion as to best practices to accomplish the same thing?  Would it be something like:  Store the len() of each element in another list and use that to choose the elements to pop AFTER the loop is finished or something?

Comment: @ddickenson I don't know what you are doing, but generally, you create a new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify the list in-place, just use list-slicing. First, set up the data:

```
l2 = [(0, ['Check In', '', '1607-584-4547', 'Avail', '10:48', '3', '1', '1']),
      (1, ['Check In', '', '1607-584-4514', 'Avail', '10:49', '2', '1', '12']),
      (2, ['Check Out', '', '1607-584-4580', 'Avail', '10:46', '2', '0', '3']),
      (3, ['Check Out', '', '1607-115-4068', 'AUX', '10:49', '0', '0', '8'])]

l1 = ['15', '15:09 WED JAN 10 2018', 'Endcrinology', '0', '20', '0:00', '', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']
```

And now, a simple for-loop:

---

```
for _, sub in l2:
    sub[:0] = l1[:4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
l1 = ['15', '15:09 WED JAN 10 2018', 'Endcrinology', '0', '20', '0:00', '', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']
l2 = [(0, ['Check In', '', '1607-584-4547', 'Avail', '10:48', '3', '1', '1']), (1, ['Check In', '', '1607-584-4514', 'Avail', '10:49', '2', '1', '12']), (2, ['Check Out', '', '1607-584-4580', 'Avail', '10:46', '2', '0', '3']), (3, ['Check Out', '', '1607-115-4068', 'AUX', '10:49', '0', '0', '8'])]
final_list = [(a, l1[:4]+b) for a, b in l2]
```

Output:

```
[(0, ['15', '15:09 WED JAN 10 2018', 'Endcrinology', '0', 'Check In', '', '1607-584-4547', 'Avail', '10:48', '3', '1', '1']), 
(1, ['15', '15:09 WED JAN 10 2018', 'Endcrinology', '0', 'Check In', '', '1607-584-4514', 'Avail', '10:49', '2', '1', '12']), 
(2, ['15', '15:09 WED JAN 10 2018', 'Endcrinology', '0', 'Check Out', '', '1607-584-4580', 'Avail', '10:46', '2', '0', '3']), 
(3, ['15', '15:09 WED JAN 10 2018', 'Endcrinology', '0', 'Check Out', '', '1607-115-4068', 'AUX', '10:49', '0', '0', '8'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your second list is

```
agentdata1 = [
    (0, ['Check In', '', '1607-584-4547', 'Avail', '10:48', '3', '1', '1']),
    (1, ['Check In', '', '1607-584-4514', 'Avail', '10:49', '2', '1', '12']),
    (2, ['Check Out', '', '1607-584-4580', 'Avail', '10:46', '2', '0', '3']),
    (3, ['Check Out', '', '1607-115-4068', 'AUX', '10:49', '0', '0', '8'])
]
```

And your first list is

```
list1 = ['15', '15:09 WED JAN 10 2018', 'Endcrinology', '0',
         '20', '0:00', '', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']
```

First we separate the first four elements of list 1:

```
four_elements_list1 = list1[:4]
```

Now, there are two possible approaches:

1. The more intuitive is:

   ```
   result = []
   for element, value in agentdata1:
       result.append((element, four_elements_list1 + value))
   ```
2. The more compact is:

   ```
   result = map(lambda (element, value): (element, four_elements_list1 + value), agentdata1)
   ```

   You can find more information about [lambda functions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) to understand it better.

Comment: This seems to have added an extra layer in there.  Rather than just adding the values it now gives as an example of the first record: 

(0, (0, ['284', '17:15 WED JAN 10 2018', 'LourdesUrologyA', '0', 'Ashleigh Nelson', '', '1607-101-2904', 'AUX', '16:21', '0', '0', '0']))

It looks like it's become a 3d array now

Comment: It should not happen, check if you are making it correctly.